# case insensitivity with sed search

Tags: sed, case-sensitivity

In a unix script, I have the line

`sed -i "/$1/s/a/b" filename`

This finds lines containing the string $1 (which is given to the script as a parameter) and, in those lines, replaces "a" with "b".

I would like this to be case-insensitive with respect to $1.  For example, if $1 is "foo", then I want the replacement to happen in all lines containing "foo" or "FOO" or "Foo", etc.   What is the best way to do this?

(Note:  The original version of this post omitted the first forward slash in the code, which is important context for understanding Kusalananda's answer.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay, got it.   `Is` instead of `s` works.  So the fixed code is:

`sed -i "/$1/Is/a/b" filename`

(This works for me in the t-shell; I have not tested it otherwise.)

Comment: oh, do you mine posting the code?

Comment: @Cyberninja :  sed -i "$1/Is/a/b" filename

Comment: @StephenKitt To be honest, they posted their answer before I posted mine. I did however totally misunderstand what they were writing due to the lack of code markup, and after re-reading it a few times I decided to keep my answer as it adds details and context. If anyone feels strongly about this, I can donate my text to this answer, alternatively make mine a community wiki.

Comment: Ah, yes @Kusalananda, I didn’t notoce the timeline — I read “okay, got it” as confirming your answer! Your answer addresses the missing `/` which is important IMO, so I’d say it’s fine to leave everything as-is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your original `sed` expression is `/$1/s/a/b/` or `/$1/ s/a/b/`, including that initial `/` character, or you would have to rely on `$1` containing an initial `/` (NOTE: The expression in the question was corrected after writing this).  This `sed` command applies a substitution on all lines addressed by a particular regular expression given by the 1st positional parameter, `$1`.

Some implementations of `sed`, like GNU `sed` and the `sed` available on macOS, can make the regular expression address match case-insensitively by using an `I` (capital i) flag, in a similar way as to how flags may be used with the `s///` command (e.g., `s///g`).

Assuming you're using a `sed` that supports this non-standard feature:

```bash
sed "/$1/I s/a/b/" file
```

This would substitute the first `a` with `b` on each line matching whatever regular expression is in `$1` case-insensitively.

Testing:

```bash
% set -- foo ; sed "/$1/I s/a/b/" <<'EXAMPLE'
heredoc> FOO a
heredoc> a foo a
heredoc> Fool abba
heredoc> Moose able
heredoc> EXAMPLE
FOO b
b foo a
Fool bbba
Moose able
```

Comment: You are right; my code (both before and after I fixed it) included the initial slash, which I failed to copy-paste into the post.  I will edit to fix this, but I hope you'll leave this informative answer up.